# Access properties in parent class initializer that are changed by child class

Tags: swift, inheritance, init, deferred, initializer

In a parent class initializer I would like to use properties that have been overwritten by the child class.

See this example:

```swift
import Foundation

class Parent
{
    var string = "Parent"
    init()
    {
        print(string) // prints "Parent", would like it to print "Child"
    }
}

class Child: Parent
{
    override init()
    {
        super.init()
        string = "Child"
    }
}

let child = Child()
```

`defer { print(string) }` wouldn’t help as it just moves the print to right after the parent class initializer before any change in the child class can happen.

What possibilities does Swift offer for this case?

Comment: You modify `string` **after** calling `super.init()`, what do you expect? `print(child.string)` does print the proper value.

Comment: It's not going to.  At the point of running it's going to print the initialised value - the parent.  This isn't the purpose of an initialiser.  Can you add to your question what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @vadian That is exactly the problem. I would like to know if there is a language feature that allows me to defer a statement to be called after all child initialization is done. In my example it is done before the child initialization is done.

Comment: @flanker Let me think

Answer (score 0):

A possible way is to implement `init(string` with a default value

```
class Parent
{
    var string : String
    
    init(string : String = "Parent")
    {
        self.string = string
        print(string)
    }
}

class Child: Parent
{
    init()
    {
        super.init(string: "Child")
    }
}

let parent = Parent() // prints "Parent"
let child = Child() // prints "Child"
```